# Google Sheets VALUE function gives wrong result

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a cell: 1:03.45 which I converted into a number using
*=VALUE(REPLACE(REPLACE(F10;2;1;" ");5;1;" "))*
Works perfectly, the result is 10345. Now I tried the cell 1:04.04 with the same functions, and I got 36985.
What causes it to happen?
Also, it does the same for 1:04.05 it gives 36986.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A3, "\D+", )*1)
```

[image]